# Drug coverage by health insurance

Tags: data-request, usa, medical, finance

I'm looking for a data set containing the copayment of all drugs for the various health insurance operators in the United States.

Comment: meps has rx events

Comment: @AnthonyDamico Thanks! Link:  [Medical Expenditure Panel Survey Home](https://meps.ahrq.gov/)